# Test 'ReactHtmlParser' using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write unit test case using Jest and Enzyme in react to test 'ReactHtmlParser'.

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

    renderData = () =>{
        const posts = this.props.data;
        return posts.map((post,index)=>{
            return <div key={post._id} className="L1-Video-Warpper">
                <div className="comp-132-video-title">{post.title}</div>
                        {
                            ReactHtmlParser(post.fileURL)
                        }
                    </div>
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can u provide a completed, minimal code? What package are you using for `ReactHtmlParser` function?

Comment: Mock it. Assert that it was called with correct argument.